# How to open new window from MVC using RedirectToAction?

Tags: c#, model-view-controller

I want to open View throe controller using RedirectToAction, how to open new window?

```
public async Task<ActionResult> RepINVPurchaseAbstract(PAbstract ObjPAbs, string ButtonValue)
            {    
             return RedirectToAction("ReportDisplay", "Common", new { area = "" });
           }
```

Any help would be appriciated.

Comment: What you mean new window? New browser instance or just tab?

Comment: Its not possible to open a new window using RedirectToAction. Instead you can pass some flags & check if flag is true then open in new tab using javascript

Answer (score 1):

It is impossible to return a result of a action to a new window, as the action was called from origin one and origin one waits for response. What I would do, is open a new window first, with specific parameters (either in URL or in JavaScript event `body.onload` that perform your action and return result directly to new window.

Answer (score 1):

Lets assume your link or button or whatever looks like this:

```
@Html.ActionLink("ActionName", "Controller")
```

add `target="_blank"` to you  to open it in new tab or window (depending on what browser you use and what browser configurations are set):

```
@Html.ActionLink("RepINVPurchaseAbstract", "YourController", null, new { target = "_blank" })
```

It will redirect to your `RepINVPurchaseAbstract` action method then will redirect to your "ReportDisplay" action and will render out your view.

Comment: Hi Sem, its ok but my requirement is first process the report and display report section in new tab, but im using your code or jquery redirect function its would be direct open without report data process.